# get_post_meta() retreivs meta from a specific post on pages, not the page currently viewd

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a simple sidebar functionality to display embed video in the sidebar. I created a meta field where admin should paste the embed video. It works as it should on posts, but on pages, `get_the_ID()` is always returning the same ID, 145, ID of one of the posts.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
$id = get_the_ID();
$video_value = get_post_meta($id, '_post_video', true);
if (! empty($video_value)) {
echo $video_value;
echo get_the_ID();
} else {
echo 'no video to show';
echo get_the_ID();
}
?>
```

I am a bit confused, so if anyone could shad some light on this... Thanks!

Comment: Multi-post, exact duplicate of [get_post_meta() retrieves meta from a specific post on pages, not the page currently viewed](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123538/get-post-meta-retrieves-meta-from-a-specific-post-on-pages-not-the-page-curre).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress, belongs to WordPress Stack Exchange and has been asked there already.

Comment: @toscho wordpress tagged questions can't be asked here as well?

Comment: Multi-posts are not welcome (you ask us to duplicate the work!), and if your question is about [programming themes, drop-ins and plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wordpress/info) it belongs to wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @toscho but why have wordpress and wordpress-themeing tags here, if they are considered off-topic?

Comment: See [this meta topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/isnt-wordpress-answers-meant-to-house-all-wordpress-questions). If it happens in a WordPress context without **depending** on WordPress it is on topic here.

Comment: @toscho thanks, I ll read it, but it just happens that I usually get quicker and better help here, than on wordpress exchange... but I see how that is just reinforcing the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this:

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID;
```

Comment: that didn't solve it, again on pages it is outputting id 145, just to be clear, i replaced `$id = get_the_ID();` with `global $post;
$id = $post->ID;`

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided on [Wordpress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123538/get-post-meta-retrieves-meta-from-a-specific-post-on-pages-not-the-page-curre)

There is some other query which replaces the main post ID. Might be another widget, some strange plugin code or something else If you have no control over the context, collect the post ID earlier:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'collect_post_id' );

function collect_post_id()
{
static $id = 0;

if ( 'template_redirect' === current_filter() )
    $id = get_the_ID();

return $id;
```

}

Instead of get_the_ID() use collect_post_id() now in your code.

`$video_value = get_post_meta( collect_post_id(), '_post_video', true );`